# How to deal with function exits on a function that has several exit points?

Tags: c

I'm more of a student than I am a seasoned programmer and the other day I was refactoring a piece of code I wrote some time ago. In there, there was a function that was rather big in code size and had a structure like this:

```
if (eval)
    return code;
...
if (different test)
    return another code;
...
```

In all there were about 6 or 7 return points some of them with cleanup code inside of the branch. Some of them also responded to erroneous situations, paths where the function wouldn't fully process the input but rather return an error code.

Even though the code was commented and all it seemed to me hard on the eyes and difficult to read. So I was wondering if there are any best practices on the matter.

Reading code from all around the net I found different approaches to this matter. For example one would follow this scheme:

```
do {
    whole body of the function;
while (false);

clean up code if necessary;
return code;
```

Mainly to be able to use `break;` sentences in different evaluations (since we were inside a loop) to exit the loop, do the cleanup if necessary and return the exit code. But that feels the same as `goto`s to me, with the limitation that they place to go to would only be forward in code.

Another one would be similar to mine, but have only one `return` statement at the end of the function and having a variable to hold error codes.

Comment: `exit(EXIT_FAILURE);` is often used at several points to fail the run of some program; there is no reason to have it once. And what clean-up do you want to do on failure?

Comment: The `exit` function doesn't exit or leave the function, it exits *the process*. When you call `exit` the whole program will end.

Comment: In C++ you can use `try` and `catch` and some exceptions. The C way uses errcodes which can encode information relevant to your program work-flow and the point of failure..

Comment: Multiple exit points are fine (although `return` should always be preferred to `exit()`, even in `main()`), what's not however is that you need manual cleanup. Your objects should have destructors doing the job (cf RAII). What are they ?

Comment: @Quentin you are assuming that it's only c++ which is not necessarily true, in c++ you should worry less about cleanup at function exit points, but you could be using dynamic allocation too, so the destructor will no be called for every object, for example if your do `new char[size];` that might need cleanup.

Comment: Also, please choose a language and stick to it so we can answer. If you're curious about both, post two distinct questions.

Comment: @iharob I originally didn't see the C tag — hence my above comment. My remark stands for C++ : if you allocate something dynamically, you should use `unique_ptr`.

Comment: To be clear: Are you asking about several exit points - as in exit the program? or several return points - as in return from function call?

Comment: @Quentin they were variables allocated in heap via `malloc()` and opened handles, depending on how far from the start was the return point some of them needed to be deallocated and closed.

Comment: Sorry everyone for the confusing question, they were return points from a function. I edited it and also selected only C as language since that's the language of the code I had.

Comment: @Claus My point is : in C++, anything needing cleanup should be, use or be wrapped into an object implementing RAII. Edit : well that doesn't stand for C of course, just keep it in mind just in case ;)

Comment: the reality is code should be clear, maintainable, structured and easily followed.  the goto statement obliterates those principles.  in the long run, the do { ... } while( false );  is the best option for the kind of logic given by the OP.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `goto` for that.

```
code = firstCode;
if (condition != 0)
    goto label;
code = secondCode;
if (anotherCondition != 0)
    goto label;

label:
    clean_up_code_if_necessary()
    exit(code); // may be you should return from the function
```

but there could be many other options depending on the specific case.

Comment: I know that many will downvote this answer, but don't be irrational about `goto`, if `goto` wasn't useful, why it's still in the language?

Comment: because the latest C standard came on 98. people still used that at the time. also , because C is close to Assembly , it still contains many Assembly elements, that doesn't make them useful.

Comment: Actually the latest C standard is C11

Comment: @user3613500 you blindly believe that this code is wrong because of the use of `goto` but I have seen some of the best open source projects use this technique, and it's so clean and easy to follow that it would be a shame if the `goto` was removed from c.

Comment: @user2079303 The only reason it's not deprecated is compatibility. Code from the last century still uses `goto`.

Comment: @dmg, sorry I removed my comment since I hadn't noticed that user3613500 claimed C98 to be the latest version which made my comment sound silly. But on the topic of my deleted comment, deprecation does not affect compatibility.

Comment: This is perfectly fine and idiomatic error handling in C. Just be ready to move this answer if OP decides to switch this question to C++ ;)

Comment: @Quentin I am ready, if the OP picks C++ i will remove it... Also I am expecting more downvotes, I can't understand how "_programmers_" can believe in `goto` as a bad thing without reasoning about it...

Comment: @Quentin now the `try`/`catch` thing is not a good answer, the OP picked c.

Comment: @iharob Despite my earlier comment I upvoted your answer, this is probably the only situation I would say using `goto` is acceptable (so long as the label's name was a bit more descriptive).  I think people just have a knee-jerk reaction to it since they either have had to use it for everything at some point in the past or who/whatever taught them to code railed against it and pointed out all the flaws.

Comment: @iharob The C answer stands ! Well, I don't understand either. It's kind of a vicious circle where people are taught that `goto` is useless and dangerous, then repeat it to you and prove it by using it wrong. It's like banning scissors as lethal and proving your point by trying to remove one of your teeth with them.

Comment: @Namfuak yes I know, or they all read the title of _`Go To Statement Considered Harmful`_ by Edsger Dijkstra, without even reading why.

Comment: @Quentin I was one of those persons taught not to use `goto` no matter what.

Comment: So using a `goto cleanup;` for example would be a better choice than the awkward `do { ... break; ... break; ... } while (false);` right?

Comment: @Claus I think it's easier to follow and read, and maintain too, but that is my opinion which might be wrong of course. Oh, BTW, good choice for the label name.

Comment: @Claus I see you are new to SO, did you take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)?

Comment: @Claus well you want to jump. What do you use, the jump instruction, or a degenerate looping instruction, that doesn't actually loop because you want to bend it into a jump instruction ? The fact that you qualify the latter as "awkward" should be a hint.

Comment: @iharob Yes, I registered a couple of days ago and I took the tour at that time, read about the no discussion just questions and answers as well. But these days going through some sites this one still seemed the better one to make the question.

Comment: In fact I believe that your question was really good, just that there are many answers to it. BTW, the `do { ... } while (0)` is useful for writing macros sometimes.

Comment: @iharob yes, but for another reason altogether (not screwing up the syntax if the macro spans several instructions).

Comment: You could use two labels to show how `goto` can help with several cleanups (something along `close_file: if(fclose(file)) { ... }; free_mem: free(foo); return error_code;`). That can't be achieved with `break`ing from a pseudo-loop. [edit: Or maybe not, another answer already did.]

Comment: @mafso, I can't because that's what mhl answer did. So let's see if the OP thinks that is more useful and picks that instead of putting that here after that answer appeared.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69330/discussion-on-answer-by-iharob-how-to-deal-with-function-exits-on-a-function-tha).

Comment: To put it bluntly, NEVER use 'goto'  Such usage turns what could have been well structured code into spaghetti code.

Comment: @user3629249 you can't use a generalization, this code is actually way easier to understand and maintain thanks to the `goto`. What you say referes to the days when programmers used `goto` for every thing that involved flow control, but this usage is actually elegant in my point of view. Why would a programmer think of that in a blind way? Something isn't wrong just because others say so, in this case this is a very elegant solution to this problem.

Comment: @user3629249 the fact that you say that, indicates that you follow blind rules that don't necessarily make sense. I was expecting many downvotes, because some programmers think that `goto` is bad without even having a good criterion, I am not trying to be offensive, you can try to prove me wrong.

Comment: @iharob I marked your answer as accepted based on the reading of the comments and the other answers, but I agree there are probably too many different situations for a general guideline to be recommended.

Comment: I will not downvote this answer. The reason it is still is in the language is for historical reasons and people need to compile old code with a newer compiler.

Answer (score 7):

Here is frequently used linux kernel idiom. When something fails, it rolls back and cleanup after previously executed code.

```
if(do_a()==FAIL)
    goto fail_a;
if(do_b()==FAIL)
    goto fail_c;
if(do_c()==FAIL)
    goto fail_c;
/* rest of the code goes here */
/* if it's ok then set err to 0 and jump to ok */
err = 0;
goto ok;
// otherwise unroll what have been done
fail_c:
    undo_c();
fail_b:
    undo_b();
fail_a:
    undo_a();
ok:
return err;
```

Comment: I didn't want to mention linux Kernel, but that's precisely where I learned it... Although, `goto ok` could just be `return 0;`.

Comment: It could. I was adhering to the 'single return point' principle.

Comment: no no, I do think your answer is good... I upvoted it, even though I have an answer in this post.

Answer (score 4):

well , we need do differentiate between C and C++ , the way of handling things is quite different between C and C++.

In C , I would recommend use an Enum which states the current state of of the code , for example:

```
enum {State1,State2,Invalid_Argument,Error}
```

then , create a function that checkes whatever it needs, then return some constant from the enum above as return value:

```
int check_statement(arg1,arg2...)
```

and at last , use a switch case on the function above:

```
   switch(check_statment(...)){
     case state1:
     ...
     return ...

    case Error:
    ...
    return..

}
```

Comment: You should remove the C++ part (as OP switched the question to C) and elaborate a bit.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, if there were calculations of calls to other functions among the return locations wouldn't this make the code less readable?

Comment: each case should be small enough to understand . if one or more cases has significant amount of lines, consider making these lines a different function and call it within the case itself