# Right way to handle errors and free memory in C

Tags: c, memory, error-handling, malloc

in some functions I need to allocate memory with malloc() and have several if..else statements, like the pseudo-code illustrates:

```
allocate memory
if condition_1
    do_stuff
    if condition_2
        do_more_stuff
    else
        error
else
    error
free allocated memory
return
```

So I allocate memory at the beginning and it would freed if everything would work well. But currently the error functions only print an error message and exit the porgram. But as I have read often that not freeing memory although when the program exits and the OS handles normally handles the freeing afterwards, it no good style. How can I free the money in a lazy way? Do I have to write an error function that takes every pointer to the memory I have allocated that has to be freed,the pointery may be of different data types? Or should i put free(ptr) before calling the error function? An error function that takes an array of pointer with data type void and freeing than all, would do this the trick?

Comment: If you call `free(ptr)` before error handling, you'll be sure `ptr` will be freed. Just a simple and straight way.

Comment: No lazy way here. The laziest would be to write function `error` which will handle the error and free the memory.

Comment: You can also write your own allocation wrapper that will keep track of all of the allocated pointers, and then just loop through them and free, but it will have some overhead, of course..

Comment: A common way to release resources from multiple error points is [goto cleanup](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/154974/is-this-a-decent-use-case-for-goto-in-c)

Comment: @black: best answer for now. It's exactly how it's done in Linux kernel, and despite that using `goto` often being criticized as bad practice, I'd say for **error handling in C** it's a best practice. Makes code much more compact and readable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to deal with function exits on a function that has several exit points?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28070379/how-to-deal-with-function-exits-on-a-function-that-has-several-exit-points)

Comment: Check the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28070405/1983495) to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28070379/how-to-deal-with-function-exits-on-a-function-that-has-several-exit-points/28070405#28070405).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have two solutions.

You can put a label where you put the call to `free` and `error`:

```
void function(void)
{
    Memory *p = malloc(sizeof(*p));
    if (condition_1) {
        do_stuff();
        if (condition_2) {
            do_more_stuff();
        } else {
            goto err;
        }
    } else {
        goto err;
    }
    free(p);
    return;
err:
    free(p);
    error();
}
```

You can also use a flag to mark an error:

```
void function(void)
{
    Memory *p = malloc(sizeof(*p));
    bool err = false;
    if (condition_1) {
        do_stuff();
        if (condition_2) {
            do_more_stuff();
        } else {
            err = true;
        }
    } else {
        err = true;
    }
    free(p);
    if (err)
        error();
}
```

I think that the second solution looks best in this case but both of them work equally well.

Comment: Thank you, the second one looks nice but in my case I have to abort before because after the if..else statements I have more code, so the first solutions works for me. But I like the second one, too. :-)

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you care about freeing all the memory when you exit the program because of error but dont want to handle all the pointers manually.

Here is an interesting thought, write a function allocMemory that returns the result of malloc but also puts the pointer into a linked list, then freeMemory that removes it from the list, and finally release all function that iterates over the list and frees all the pointers. 
Use the allocMemory and freeMomory function instead of malloc and free, and call the freeMemory function in case of error.

Comment: Ok, sounds interesting, I guess I am going to try this way. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use goto. Use a one-time while. Also, if you need an error flag, default it to true instead of false to save code:

```
...malloc...
err = 1;
do {
    ...
    if <condition> break;
    ...
    if <condition> break;
    ...
    if <condition> break;
    ...
    err = 0;
} while (0);
...free...
if (err) ...
```