# Stone codechef: What is wrong with the code?

Tags: c

I am new to coding and finding my way!! I am solving a problem at codechef http://www.codechef.com/problems/RRSTONE.
All tests cases are passed at my side but the answer is still wrong. Any Help???

```
//codechef stones
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned int size;  //N=size
    unsigned long int k;    //k = K
    scanf("%u %lu",&size,&k);
    long int a[size], max;
    int i,j;

    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
        scanf("%lu",&a[i]);

    i=j=0;

    if(k==0)
        goto printing;
    if(k%2==1)
        k=1;
    else
        k=2;

    for(j=0;j<k;j++)
    {
        max=a[0];
        for(i=0;i<size-1;i++)
        {
            if(max<a[i])
                max=a[i];
        }
        for(i=0;i<size;i++)
            a[i]=max-a[i];
    }

    printing:   //removed this comment
    for(i=0;i<size-1;i++)
        printf("%d ",a[i]);

    printf("%d",a[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does `goto printing;` do within your code? Does your code compile without any errors/warnings?

Comment: I did not know people are still using `goto`

Comment: @EdHeal `goto` is very useful, but in this case it makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: @iharob - is it not useful. There are better methods. Have not seen it in production code from more than 20 years

Comment: @EdHeal You obviously have not seen the Linux kernel source, for one example. In c++ it's completely useless but in c it's very useful.

Comment: That code is quite old

Comment: @EdHeal Go [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28070405/1983495) and downvote my answer then.

Comment: why do you people discourage newbies like me for asking question here?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I suggest you should look at the criteria properly.

> Constraints

- 1 <= N <= 105
- 0 <= K <= 109
- Ai does not exceed **2 * 10^9** by it's absolute value.

  Here is modified code try with this.

And one more thing: Since you are learning understand the code first.

```
#include<stdio.h>
 
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned int size;  //N=size
    unsigned long int k;    //k = K
    scanf("%u %lu",&size,&k);
    long long int a[size], max;     //CHANGE HERE!!!! and so forth for long long
    int i,j;
    
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
        scanf("%lld",&a[i]);
    
    i=j=0;
    
    if(k!=0)
    {
        if(k%2==1)
            k=1;
        else
            k=2;
    
        for(j=0;j<k;j++)
        {
            max=a[0];
            for(i=1;i<size;i++)
            {
                if(max<a[i])
                    max=a[i];
            }
            for(i=0;i<size;i++)
                a[i]=max-a[i];
        }
    }
    
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
        printf("%lld ",a[i]);
        
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: Sorry I forgot to put this note. There is issue sometimes with **goto** when you are using online compilers, so better to try with a clean approach and make sure you are selecting the correct option for source language (**C-gcc or C99 whatever you're using**) . Earlier I have experienced the same.

Comment: You know that `scanf()` returns a value don't you?

Comment: I don't get your question. What do you want say exactly?

Comment: 2 * 10^9 fits in `long`.

Comment: @ns12 you ignore it...

Comment: I am trying with this. But why -1 to answer? Is it wrong?

Comment: Not my downvote, but if all you did was change it to `long long` then it isn't necessary as I said. By the way, you should explain what to fix instead of just dumping a block of code.

Comment: Hooray!!! That worked. It worked with **long long?** only not with **long**. Thanks @ns12

Comment: @interjay That's why I used **long long**.  I don't know why this happens with a codechef compiler.